# Anova table by variable

Tags: r, anova, gamlss

I'm using 'gamlss' from the package 'gamlss' (version 5.4-1) in R for a generalized additive model for location scale and shape.

My model looks like this
`propvoc3 = gamlss(proporcion.voc ~ familiaridad * proporcion)`

When I want to see the Anova table I get this output

```
Mu link function:  identity
Mu Coefficients:
                                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                              5.625e-01  9.476e-02   5.936  1.9e-06 ***
familiaridaddesconocido                 -1.094e-01  1.059e-01  -1.032  0.31042    
proporcionmayor                          4.375e-01  1.340e-01   3.265  0.00281 ** 
proporcionmenor                          1.822e-17  1.340e-01   0.000  1.00000    
familiaridaddesconocido:proporcionmayor -3.281e-01  1.708e-01  -1.921  0.06464 .  
familiaridaddesconocido:proporcionmenor  5.469e-01  1.708e-01   3.201  0.00331 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I just want to know if there is a way to get the values just by variable and not by every term?